# Points3D Function in R

Tags: r

I have the scatterplot3d package installed in R. When I load it with library(scatterplot3d) or require(scatterplot3d) I am able to create a 3d scatter plot. However, when I try to use the points3d function I get the following error:

`Error: could not find function "points3d"`

I tried reinstalling the package to no avail (both inside R and as a tarball using `R CMD INSTALL` in the command line). I am running Xubuntu 12.10 kernel 3.8.7-030807-generic and R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01).

Entering `locate points3d` in the command line gave me no results.

I also tried the par.mar default settings command as explained in the manual.

Comment: Maybe you should install `rgl` package ?

Comment: **scatterplot3d** comes with excellent documentation, which you should read carefully. (To view it, type `vignette("s3d")` from within an R session.) See the example on page 12 for how to access `points3d`, and the whole of Section 3.2 for an explanation of why **scatterplot** puts its functions where it does.

Answer (score 5):

`scatterplot3d` does an interesting object-oriented twist on the usual R practice. The object returned from the function call includes the points3d function as built-in part of the object but it is not in the Global environment. It is intended that you add to the existing plot-object using that "attached" function that is not a free-living organism but rather a domesticated animal that only exists in the object corral, so you would use this as your syntax:

```
  object$point3d(x,y,z)
```

I do "feel your pain" but can show you how to overcome the frustration, since I created a working example yesterday: [Using scatterplot3d to plot a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026610/using-scatterplot3d-to-plot-a-sphere/16026987#16026987)

Answer (score 0):

You need to intall the package [plot3D](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plot3D/versions/1.1.1/topics/plot3D-package) in the usual way via

```
install.packages("plot3D")
```

Then you just need to import, generate the dataset and use the function `points3D()`

```
library(plot3D)
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
z = x + y + rnorm(100,0,1)

points3D(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000))
```

This is the plot generated by the code above

[image: points3D R]